# How do you get a C# web app to "catch up"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I've got this app I'm writing for our Intranet using C#/.Net.  In one place, I'm checking a value on an OnLeave event to auto-fill some fields.  The problem is, if a user goes directly from the field to the Submit button, the OnLeave event fires but the fields don't fill in.

I was thinking about the DoEvents in VBA, and it looks like I could possibly use "Application.DoEvents", but that underlines itself in red when I try it.  I also found something called "Render()", but that underlines itself in blue when I try it.

Can anyone tell me how to have this code "catch up" to itself so all my data is rendered properly?  Please keep in mind I'm still somewhat new to C# so if you could be as explicit/thorough as possible I'd appreciate it.

**EDIT**

I have this code as the OnLeave event of a textbox:

```
    protected void txtClientID_OnLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str2))
        {
            //Query the Reports table to find the record associated with the selected report
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation WHERE CLIENT_ID =  '" + txtClientID.Text + "'", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader DT1 = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // If the SQL returns any records, process the info
                    if (DT1.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (DT1.Read())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                int TaskID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTask.SelectedValue);

                                // This should allow Client ID to autofill if Eligibility --> Enrollment records are used.
                                //    Add more Task IDs to this list if necessary.
                                List<int> list = new List<int>() { 154, 156, 157, 158, 160, 161, 165 };
                                if (list.Contains(TaskID))
                                {
                                    //lblAccountName.Text = (DT1["CUST_NM"].ToString());
                                    Label2.Text = (DT1["CUST_NM"].ToString());
                                    //lblAccountName.Visible = true;
                                    TBAccountNum.Text = (DT1["CUST_NUM"].ToString());
                                    TBAccountNum.Visible = true;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ae)
                            {
                                Response.Write(ae.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // If the SQL returns no records, return a static "No Records Found" message
                    else
                    {
                        //lblAccountName.Text = "No Matching Account Name";
                        Label2.Text = "No Matching Account Name";
                        //lblAccountName.Visible = true;
                        TBAccountNum.Text = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I also have a Submit button, and when the button is pressed, the first thing I want to do is make sure all the fields that were supposed to be filled in by this OnLeave even actually get filled in.  The problem is, if I step through it they all have values, but if I just run it the values never appear on the screen.

I also tried "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);" on a recommendation I saw on another site, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I think you'd better post some code, because you're way off.

Comment: Execute the auto-fill code on the submit click if those fields are blank? Hard to know what's going on without some code.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Web Forms? In 2014?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using web forms properly, even in 2014. It just seems like he's not really sure what he's doing.

Comment: I could post it (well, the relevant parts), but it's about 30,000 lines with a lot of functions involved.  I was hoping maybe there was some command, like DoEvents in VBA, that would be more or less universal.

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: +1 for using using() !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can move that code into its own method `RefreshData` or something. Call this method inside `txtClientID_OnLeave`. Then in your button submit click event, check if those textboxes are empty. If they are, call the `RefreshData` method before doing anything else in the click event.

You might go a bit further and set a flag when `RefreshData` is called and check this flag in the button submit event instead of checking that the textboxes are empty. If the user writes in the textboxes, the submit click wont retrieve the data when it otherwise should.

```
private bool _retrievedData = false;

public void RefreshData() {
    // do everything you were doing inside the `txtClientID_OnLeave` handler
    // make sure to set this flag only if the data was successfully retrieved
    // the bottom of the `try` should be good
    _retrievedData = true;
}

public void txtClientID_OnLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    RefreshData();
}

public void yourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (_retrievedData == false)
        RefreshData();

    // do whatever you were doing in this handler because now your textboxes have the
    // data it would have if you had left the textbox without going straight to submit
}
```

Now I'm sure there are cleaner ways to handle this but since your submit reads off the textboxes all you really need is to fill in the textboxes before the submit handler does its thing.